# Unable to run imported project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a few projects that were previously tested to be working in 1 PC.

I've since moved to another Windows XP PC, and I've setup the development tools on this XP system. I've downloaded and installed the following in order:
1. Eclipse Classic 3.6.1
2. JDK v6(jdk-6u23-windows-i586.exe)
3. Android SDK Tools rev8(installer_r08-windows.exe)
4. SDK Platform v2.3/2.2, Google APIs, Android API8, rev2, Google USB driver, rev4
5. ADT 8.0.1

I created a new empty project just to make sure things are working, and I seem to be able to get that new project to run on the emulator just fine. However, when I imported an existing project into the workspace, I get a bunch of errors, such as:
"The import java.util cannot be resolved"
"The import android cannot be resolved"

When I look at Project Properties->Java Build Path, it shows "Unable to get system library for the project" under "Libraries" and "Order and Export". What's wrong?

I've also tried copying and pasting the .java files and main.xml files from the imported project to the new project, and it runs correctly...but somehow the imported project doesn't.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the project configured for an older API level for which you don't have the SDK installed?

Comment: Sounds very similar to this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095322/android-eclipse-classpath-want-to-add-classpath-container-path-but-eclipse-won) See if that link helps you at all.

Comment: In case anyone googles this up, I just had the same problem and solved it by removing the library in the build path for the project and then adding it again. None of the answers below worked for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Eclipse Classpath - want to add classpath container path but eclipse won't let me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095322/android-eclipse-classpath-want-to-add-classpath-container-path-but-eclipse-won)

Answer (score 68):

1. Right click on project name, open properties.
2. Select Java Build Path (from left menus)
3. Under the "Libraries" tab, find the entry 'Unable to get system library for project', select it then click on the Remove button.
4. Select Android (from left menus), tick on the version of android you want to target.
5. Select Project menu (main top level menu), select Clean... Select OK.
6. Right click on project name again, go down to Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

That should do the trick and add Android X.X (version you selected) to your project, and the imported project should start working.

Enjoy.

Comment: Cheers, I wouldn't mind if @Goi would give me the magical check-mark, but at least I can help others out. Thanks for the up-votes.

Comment: This won't work for me - I check the version and it won't stay selected after I hit "Apply"

Comment: Sometimes you have to repeat the procedure more than once, or alternatively you can try deleting the project.properties file first.

Comment: Doesn't work at all. After finishing the steps, the android fix project properties complains about "unable to resolve target 'android-4'.

Answer (score 3):

I think your project does not have project target name or missing. And it's simple go to main menu : `project->properties->android` (from left panel) then mark a project target name as you need for your project. After this it should work if not then clean your project like this : `project->clean..>select` (clean projects selected below )`->` mark your project then click `ok`. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on Run Configurations
2. Click on icon at top left corner(New launch configuration)
3. Choose Project
4. Click run !