# Building and including an external module in an Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I would like to include [this plist parser module](https://github.com/tenaciousRas/android-plist-parser) in my Android application, ideally without just copying the entire module source into my source tree (if that would even work).

I have successfully added the module as a project into Eclipse (3.7.0) and resolved errors by fixing the build path to include Android 2.1, which is what I am using.  However, now I'm stuck.  All of the information on using external libraries with your Android project I can find expect you to have a JAR of the library, but I only have this source code.  I can run the plist parser module as an Android application, which appears to compile an .apk, but that doesn't actually do anything because it's not a standalone application.  Any options to just build the module without running it are greyed out in the Eclipse interface.

How can I either build this module into a .jar for inclusion, or include it in some other way?

Edit: In order to clear the errors in the module after I added it to Eclipse, I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9926058/471671).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either convert the whole thing to a [library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) or simply include the source code in your app's project. To create a library project, you can import the project from github, and after you get it compile, remove any activities, go to the project's Properties->Android and check the 'Is a library' check box. Then add it as a dependency to your own project.

Comment: I made it into a library, but where do I add it as a dependency?  Is that separate from adding it to the build path?

Comment: Project Properties->Android, in the lower part there is a 'Library' section, click 'Add' -- http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject And reading the docs usually helps :)

Comment: Okay, that seemed to work.  Thank you!

Indeed, reading the docs usually helps, but with all of the different ways to manage build deps in Java and with all of the bloat of Eclipse it's difficult to figure out which docs to refer to.