# application crash report but ok on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I find it weird that the application for android works fine on Emulator..

but in real device, it crashes and give the following error (via developer console):

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The import com.recipes cannot be resolved

at com.etraks.mauritianrecipes.app.SplashScreen.<init>(SplashScreen.java:3)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1027)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1885)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my question is why does such crash does not occur on the emulator?

Comment: Will you please try to uninstall previous one and then re-install.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497076/unable-to-run-imported-project

Answer (score 0):

If you have the import  com.recipes in a jar file go to properties->javabuildpath->order and export . Include the jar file here as well (mark it checked) if not already included.