# I get an exception using java on android (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError), why?

Tags: java, android, exception, audio

This is the line I run:

```
AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile1));
```

This is the exception I get (From LogCat):

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem

This is an old program that I wrote a year ago and then it worked perfectly.
Why do I get this exception and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AudioSystem` is part of JavaSound, and JavaSound is part of the desktop JVM/SDK. JavaSound is NOT present in the Android JVM/SDK, so your old code will not compile on any current Android SDK.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html for the Android audio functionality outline: you will need to port your old code to use the Android SDK classes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the classpath isn't set correctly. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095322/android-eclipse-classpath-want-to-add-classpath-container-path-but-eclipse-won) for some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly means class AudioSystem is not present in your project. May be you were referencing some libraries which may be missing now.