# Cant use AudioFileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file); in android?

Tags: java, android, file

I've been trying to figure out for the life of me how to cut up a certain amount of milliseconds out of a sample. My first problem is when I insert this code into eclipse. It tells me AudioInputStream, AudioFileFormat and FileFormat are not available. If I can't use FileFormat then i can't pass methods into other methods to get the correct calculations to save the correct amount of music. I can't even import them. But more importantly, how can I change the parameter "secondstocopy" into "millisecondstocopy" without ruining the integrity of the algorithm? Still new to java, thank you for your help!

//edit// `FileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);` It seems I can't use this bit of code for android. The `getAudioFileFormat` doesn't work. Nor can I calculate the fram rate because of.. `int bytesPerSecond = format. * (int)format.getFrameRate();` How do I properly get the format and frame rate with media player so that I can calculate the `bytesPerSecond` and `secondsToCopy`?

AudioSystem is part of JavaSound, and JavaSound is part of the desktop JVM/SDK. JavaSound is NOT present in the Android JVM/SDK, so your old code will not compile on any current Android SDK. [I get an exception using java on android (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError), why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149155/i-get-an-exception-using-java-on-android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-why)

How can I calculate the file format and fram rate and stuff without the javasound jvm/sdk. I can tell you now that the sounds are 44100 and 16 bit something. In the get info pane of the recording file, it says total bit rate: 128,000 with two audio channels. I'm not good with encoding stuff but I'm recording the audio with a program on mac called wiretap pro. It tells me the the parameters.

```
 import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

class AudioFileProcessor {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    copyAudio("/tmp/uke.wav", "/tmp/uke-shortened.wav", ƒ, 1);
  }

  public static void copyAudio(String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, int                   startSecond, int secondsToCopy)  {
    AudioInputStream inputStream = null;
    AudioInputStream shortenedStream = null;
    try {
      File file = new File(sourceFileName);
      AudioFileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
      AudioFormat format = fileFormat.getFormat();
      inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
      int bytesPerSecond = format.getFrameSize() * (int)format.getFrameRate();
      inputStream.skip(startSecond * bytesPerSecond);
      long framesOfAudioToCopy = secondsToCopy * (int)format.getFrameRate();
      shortenedStream = new AudioInputStream(inputStream, format, framesOfAudioToCopy);
      File destinationFile = new File(destinationFileName);
      AudioSystem.write(shortenedStream, fileFormat.getType(), destinationFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      println(e);
    } finally {
      if (inputStream != null) try { inputStream.close(); } catch (Exception e) { println(e); }
      if (shortenedStream != null) try { shortenedStream.close(); } catch (Exception e) { println(e); }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As you all but point out in the oddly quoted passage in the middle of your question, you must use (and import) the Android audio classes rather than javax.sound ones. For example, `import android.media.AudioFormat` rather than `import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat`  Of course the two APIs are not directly interchangeable; you will have to write at least this subsystem of your code to target Android (and no, you can't easily write your own wrappers with the javax names to provide equivalent functionality, as the Android toolchain normally blocks you from placing things in the javax namespace)

Comment: Thank you sir. I'm new to this. When you say.. " (and no, you can't easily write your own wrappers with the javax names to provide equivalent functionality, as the Android toolchain normally blocks you from placing things in the javax namespace)" I don't know what that means either so I don't think I'm doing that. Mr. @ChrisStratton , what I'm trying to do is just cut a sample 700 - 900 milliseconds long from a previously played sample. I will set the amount of milli seconds depending on the song being played. I just wish I could get this working.

Comment: See if the classes you want to use are provided on Android, and if so import them.  If not, see what is provided, and adapt your code to that.  If nothing fits, it's ultimately only data and you can handle it yourself.

Comment: and I cant use import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat .. it's not allowing me to...

Comment: Yes, as I already said those classes are not available on Android.  You'll need to adapt your program to what is available, or create this functionality from scratch (in your own namespaces, the javax one being nominally prohibited)

Comment: I appreciate your perspective, this problem is simple. I'm not a programmer. I'm an amateur. I haven't gone to school or anything so a lot of the questions I may be asking may seem dumb to you. Sorry.

Comment: You might want to peruse some Android audio examples to get an idea of what is available and how it is used.

Comment: ... i see.. i was about to whine and say that it isn't possible. but there are ringtone apps that allow you to cut a piece that you want. I'll just have to put on my thinking cap and create and solve another problem . I've spent too much time on this problem and it's getting me no where. Just venting. Maybe I'll go play with some Fragments or something.. ionno

Comment: It is indeed possible... a program to accomplish it by simply manipulating the raw data could have been written already in the lifetime of this exchange.  However, most would consider it preferable to do it with the audio data handling APIs provided by the platform.  And as those are not the javax.sound ones, it will take some familiarization.

Comment: i want to show you this algorithm i came up with.. to slice the music.. but also maybe you could make since of what i'm trying to do.. @ChrisStratton .. please..

Comment: Yes, you can calculate a duration from a sample rate and format information, either manually or with the aid of some of the provided things.  But you are going to need to learn how to do that yourself.

Comment: @ChrisStratton i will send you only one or two more messages cause i know you don't have all day. i just peeked at your profile and.. yeah.. you don't have time for such a trivial issue. i strive to be like you though!! you just don't understand.. i'm about 8 - 10 years behind.. but i stumbled upon this industry because i used to try to capitalize on SEO autoblogs and the likes.. anyway.. you sir.. are on another planet.. so my last question is.. what info or help.. or variables you know i should need.. what info can you provide me to give me the biggest push forward so that i may.. you get it

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the purpose of this site.  Please delete the comment containing your personal email address.