# Android NoClassDefFoundError when starting new activity thru intent

Tags: java, android, class

Weird issue here, doing something very trivial:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i = new Intent(AutoVisionActivity.this, ExampleLoad3DSFile.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml I have:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.ExampleLoad3DSFile"></activity>
```

And the class itself (ExampleLoad3DSFile) is in the same package as my main activity's onCreate from above. I've tried the standard clean project, refresh, and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12702315/624869 but to no avail.

What gives?

Comment: clean and refresh your project...

Comment: You should change to `<activity android:name=".ExampleLoad3DSFile"></activity>` in manifeast.

Comment: both activity are in same packge then:  <activity android:name=".ExampleLoad3DSFile"></activity>

Comment: post your entire application tag of AndroidManifest file.

Comment: i think your manifest is bad, give it full package name and try like that

Answer (score 1):

you should either give the full package name or the class name of the activity with the dot(.) prefixed if it is in the same package while declaring the activity.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through same error but finally i found the reason why it occur while i was working on [MIN3D](http://code.google.com/p/min3d/) project .

```
IParser parser = Parser.createParser(Parser.Type.MAX_3DS,
            getResources(), "com.min3d.sampleProject1:raw/monster_high", false);
```

Make sure you are using same the package name in `ExampleLoad3DSFile`  class what you are using in your project .