# NoClassDefFoundError Android Project

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

First of all, I know there are plenty of questions/answers about this topic, I've read most of them but still getting the error:

```
05-17 02:57:06.522: E/AndroidRuntime(17073): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ar.com.package.android.MainActivity
```

The project worked just fine until I updated Eclipse from 21 to 22.

I have tried everything I could: I checked the manifest; Cleaned the project; checked my build path, tried the app in different android version, set java compliance level to 1.6 (libraries too), etc. I just can't figure out what the problem is.

Here's my manifest, I couldn't find anything wrong with it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ar.com.package.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/> 

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<permission
    android:name="ar.com.package.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ar.com.package.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" 
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">


    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="my key"/>


    <activity
        android:name="ar.com.package.android.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="ar.com.package.android.MainActivity"
        android:logo="@drawable/logo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
         >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="ar.com.package.android.SearchForm"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_form"
        android:parentActivityName="ar.com.package.android.MainActivity"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="ar.com.package.android.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Any help is welcome. I'll keep researching, if I get the answer I'll post it.

EDIT

Here's the MainActivity code:

```
package ar.com.package.android;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.*;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.OnCloseListener;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.OnOpenListener;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

private SlidingMenu menu;
private Toast toast;
private long lastBackPressTime = 0;
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // slidemenu
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu);

    setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);

    menu = getSlidingMenu();
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffset(100);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.setSlidingEnabled(false);

    menu.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClose() {
            menu.setSlidingEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    menu.setOnOpenListener(new OnOpenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOpen() {
            menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

    // ---slide menu

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Maps no esta disponible.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {


        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                -26.8175915814614, -65.22274105834958), 13));

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        toggle();
        return true;

    case R.id.action_search:
        final int RESULT = 1;
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                SearchForm.class), RESULT);
        return true;

    case R.id.action_lineas:
        showDialogLineas();
        return true;

    case R.id.action_acercade:
        showDialogAcercaDe();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && !menu.isMenuShowing()) {

        if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) {
            toast = Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Presione Atrás nuevamente para cerrar",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            if (toast != null) {
                toast.cancel();
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void onResultadosClicked(View view) {
    showMenu();
}

public void showDialogLineas(){
    DialogFragment dialog = new LineasDialog();
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Lineas");
}

public void showDialogAcercaDe(){
    DialogFragment dialog = new AcercaDeDialog();
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Acerca");
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the MainActivity code as well?

Comment: have you referred google play services library in your map project correctly? This is my guess you are not referring to gogole play services library. second you should use this in manifest      <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="your key"/> instead of this <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="ar.com.tucubondi.android.MainActivity" />

Comment: The problem was the 21 -> 22 update I solved it using timisus' link.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Strange I'm just reviewing this question and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 34):

Try going to **Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export** and ensure **Android Private Libraries** are checked for your project and for all other library projects you are using.

Comment: +1 i tried many solutions but only this got worked, thanks:)

Comment: worked for me - great catch

Comment: How can I do this setting in AndroidStudio?

Comment: In my case it checked in all libraries and I still got the same exception.

Comment: Any solution for Android Studio?

Comment: Managed to get the error on Android Studio. Any solutions yet? @androidevil

Comment: @AA_PV I don't remember what I did in that time. Coincidentally, I'm having this issue. Looking for a solution now.

Comment: I think I ran into the problem on changing the gradle version in the build file for a library. I don't remember resolving this myself now, try running with lower version of gradle