# NoClassFoundError after deleting a java file in android

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I had deleted an activity named `ProductList_Activity.java` file. Now when I run the app it crashes with the following error. How to fix it?

error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(23686): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(23686): Process: com.esouqatar.customer, PID: 23686
E/AndroidRuntime(23686): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.esouqatar.customer/com.esouqatar.customer.ProductList_Activity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.esouqatar.customer.ProductList_Activity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.esouqatar.customer-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5315)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)             
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:736)   
E/AndroidRuntime(23686): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.esouqatar.customer.ProductList_Activity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.esouqatar.customer-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    ... 10 more
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.esouqatar.customer.ProductList_Activity
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):        ... 13 more
E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: have you removed activity form manifest??

Comment: Have you removed all objects of the class after you deleted it?

Comment: Have you rebuild your entire project?

Comment: I have removed it from the manifest

Comment: I rebuild d project..thanx its working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602640/noclassdeffounderror-android-project

Comment: @Tiny Kindly review my answer .Hope this perfect .

Answer (score 4):

[NoClassDefFoundError](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html): is thrown when the definition of class in not available during `runtime`. This error also indicates that the definition of the class was found during the compilation of the application, but it is not available in the application’s `classpath during runtime`.More info to visit [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602640/noclassdeffounderror-android-project).

### How To Solve

In general, **`Clean & Rebuild Project Then Restart`** .
Otherwise,

Verify that all required Java classes are included in the application’s classpath. The most common mistake is not to include all the necessary classes, before starting to execute a Java application that has dependencies on some external libraries.[Courtesy](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-how-to-solve-no-class-def-found-error/)

Answer (score 0):

Some Where in your code the class is still in use. Either find and remove class instatiation or restore the file if you need the file.

Comment: This could be a comment

Comment: @Robert sorry but can't comment new here need to get some reputation first :P

Answer (score -1):

Right click on your project and then **Run As -> Java Application**

This solved the issue for me.