# Android Google Map API v2 NoClassDefFoundError error

Tags: android, google-maps

I downloaded google map api v2 sample and followed official tutorial on google website (installed and added google play services) but i got NoClassDefFoundError error when run sample as below

```
07-26 02:01:04.821: I/Process(620): Sending signal. PID: 620 SIG: 9
07-26 02:01:18.559: W/dalvikvm(682): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/mapdemo/BasicMapActivity; (80)
07-26 02:01:18.559: W/dalvikvm(682): Link of class 'Lcom/example/mapdemo/BasicMapActivity;' failed
07-26 02:01:18.559: E/dalvikvm(682): Could not find class 'com.example.mapdemo.BasicMapActivity', referenced from method com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity.<clinit>
07-26 02:01:18.559: W/dalvikvm(682): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 128 (Lcom/example/mapdemo/BasicMapActivity;) in Lcom/example/mapdemo/MainActivity;
07-26 02:01:18.559: D/dalvikvm(682): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x000d
07-26 02:01:18.658: W/dalvikvm(682): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/mapdemo/MainActivity;
07-26 02:01:18.658: W/dalvikvm(682): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/mapdemo/MainActivity;)
07-26 02:01:18.676: D/AndroidRuntime(682): Shutting down VM
07-26 02:01:18.676: W/dalvikvm(682): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1301)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.mapdemo.BasicMapActivity
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:100)
07-26 02:01:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  ... 15 more
07-26 02:06:18.960: I/Process(682): Sending signal. PID: 682 SIG: 9
```

I got google api key by combine SHA 1 fingerprint at "Window > Preferences > Android > Build > SHA 1 fingerprint" with google sample package name "com.example.mapdemo"

Please help me, sorry for my english, thanks very much.

---

I changed target sdk and emulator is 4.0, that error is disappeared but i got a new  is "Google play services is missiong".

Then, i changed target sdk and emulator is 4.2.2, i got error "google play services out of date. requires 3159100 but found 3136130"

Please help me.

Comment: post your MainActivty class

Comment: Have you added your MAP KEY in your manifest file ? Also post your `MainActivity.java` file code.

Comment: try this link and follow each step http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/07/google-map-android-api-v2-with-location.html

Comment: I run google sample on official site

Comment: @sunil: i followed your tutorial but got ClassNotFoundException error. Please help me

Comment: did you make java build path of android support library if have below version of API. And also add the library of the google play service.It should be be work

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to "Properties" of the project.
2. Select "Java Build Path"
3. Select "Order and Export" Tab
4. You should see the selected project's "src" and "gen" paths and dependencies here.
5. The order how they listed were first "src" and then "gen" path
6. I switch them, so that "gen" folder is build before the "src"

**reference** https://stackoverflow.com/a/12702315/2398886

Comment: Thanks you, but unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

Still look at the Properties, instead of switch the positions, try to select all the libs.

I did this and it solves my problem.

[image]

Notice: You can run the Map API sample code now, but the Google Map app in emulator still shows nothing. If you want to run this app, you need to install Google Play Service app first.