# Google official Sample navigation Drawer with API 8

Tags: android, sample, slidingmenu, navigation-drawer

I have a problem with Navigation Drawer Sample of Google when I put android:minSdkVersion="8" in my manifest.xml
Sample doesn't works in API 8 but I would like to run with this API, and I don't know why he doesn't works

**My first eror is:**

```
Could not find class 'com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity$PlanetFragment', referenced from method com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity.selectItem
```

**I will try all solutions :**

[Could not find class XXX referenced from method XXX.<YYY>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765910/could-not-find-class-xxx-referenced-from-method-xxx-yyy)

[could not find class referenced from method android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437105/could-not-find-class-referenced-from-method-android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderr)

But nothing work even if I restart or clean...

I have in my package :

1. Android Private Libraries
2. Android Dependencies
3. Google APIs
4. MainActivity/src
5. MainActivity/gen

Comment: you will need support library

Comment: I have android-support-v4.jar in my libs folder @Raghunandan

Answer (score 0):

try this from nicolas 
https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer

Remember to update the android-support-v4.jar to the latest version (minimum required revision 13).