# Android: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for class extended from "java" library

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, opencsv

Following is the snap shot of the eclipse's package explorer. I use the opencsv library for the app project. I added the jar to referenced libraries in main project. I define a class 'X' in main project that extends a class from the jar library project.

When I create an instance of class 'X' it gives

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

I tried to add the library in *Properties>Android>Add...* but since the opencsv is a java project and not android library project, it doesnt show up in the list to select.

Somehting missing?

[image]

Comment: Please mention the full stackTrace.

Comment: @Jhanvi Nothing special in the stacktrace. I try 'DIPReader rdr = new DIPReader(filename)' and it crashes. `DIPReader` extends `CSVReader` class from the opencsv library..

Comment: Try reading this two posts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android

Comment: Must Check that jar file also in **libs** folder.

Comment: @nico the second did help in correcting the Order of the library in Order & Export window. but still I get the error..

Comment: @Piyush Gupta There is another library in `Android Dependences` folder. I didnt have to add it to the libs folder. And it works fine. That is not the issue.

Comment: You'll only get superficial answers unless you tell people which class exactly is giving NoClassDefFoundError. Suggest you to follow this to understand and debug - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Comment: have a look on my post. this should helo you

Answer (score 0):

Did you mark that library for export? Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export?

Answer (score 0):

check private libraries and dependancies as export entities for your library project.
see this attachment[image: click here]

Answer (score 0):

You have here 2 possibilities:

1. Transform you opencv project into android library project and bind it as library in your main project
2. Copy & paste the openCSV-2.3.jar in the `libs` folder from your main project. It will apprears automatically in `references libraries`