# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError UserAgentConfig$Callbacks with Twilio

Tags: android

I am using Twilio Client Android sdk but failing with this error while try to run it :-

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class "Lcom/twilio/client/impl/useragent/config/UserAgentConfig$Callbacks;" not found
```

I have include twilioclient-android-1.1.2-3635733.jar what went wrong anyone

What should be the Order-
Current Order

```
Android 4.4.2
Android Private Libraries
Android Dependencies
Project/gen
Project/src
```

Comment: Follow this it may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android

Comment: Try adding jar to build path.

Comment: Can you check the order

Comment: Does it has to do something with **<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />** But The app works fine it emulators I have check on three as of 4.2,4.3 and 4.4 it is just that it fails with above error when runned on device not in emulator any guess

Comment: Now I have tried ' private static void fixClassLoaderIssue()
    {
        ClassLoader myClassLoader = MonkeyPhone.class.getClassLoader();
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(myClassLoader);
    }' It doesnt faile with above error it now fail with 'art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: java_object == null'

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

> project-> config build path-> order and export-> move dependent project on top

and

> this error is also generated when you make an app that uses the Google API (such as Maps) but run it on a device that targets the Android API.

thats it.

Comment: Hi, shylendra I have tried all possibility from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android but I am checking it for hours and hours now but is still there by the way I am getting this error with ANDROID Twilio Client sdk have you worked with Twilio lib before

Comment: @shivam singh No, sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using `Proguard` i.e, if `minifyEnabled` is set to `true` in the `build.gradle` file, then it is possible that Proguard is obfuscating your code. So make sure you use the Proguard rules for Twillio, as written in the [Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android#proguard-exception):

```
-keep class com.twilio.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check you runtime in 'developer options' -> 'select runtime' if you use ART just change it to Dalvik to avoid this error. Maybe it's not a solution for you but I didn't find another way to fix this error.