# Android launcher activity says NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, listadapter

I have a sample android app got from this [web](http://www.coderzheaven.com/tag/faster-loading-images-in-gridviews-or-listviews-in-android-using-menory-caching/).While running this project it shows 
NoClassDefFoundError in logcat i cant find what is the problem here some one please help me to fix this

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText etResponse;
    TextView tvIsConnected;
    JSONObject jObject;
    JSONArray jCountries = null;
    String image_first[];
    String image_second[];
    ArrayList<String> items;
    ListAdapter list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // check if you are connected or not
        if(isConnected()){
            // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://kodspider.com/Android_Test/index.php"/*"http://hmkcode.appspot.com/rest/controller/get.json"*/);


    }

    public static String GET(String url){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }

    public boolean isConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) 
                return true;
            else
                return false;   
    }
    public class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            return GET(urls[0]);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray articles = json.getJSONArray("images");
                 image_first =new String[json.getJSONArray("images").length()];  //initializtion
                  image_second =new String[json.getJSONArray("images").length()];

                     items = new ArrayList<String>();

                for(int i=0;i<json.getJSONArray("images").length();i++){

                items.add(image_first[i] = (articles.getJSONObject(i).optString("image_first")));
                //image_second[i]= (articles.getJSONObject(i).optString("image_second"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                }
             list = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);

            GridView grid = new GridView(MainActivity.this);

            grid.setAdapter(list);

            grid.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);

            setContentView(grid);
       }
    }
}
```

**ListAdapter.java**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> items;
    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;

        // Get memory class of this device, exceeding this amount will throw an
        // OutOfMemory exception.
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {

            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                // The cache size will be measured in bytes rather than number
                // of items.
                return bitmap.getByteCount();
            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return items.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ImageView img = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            img = new ImageView(context);
            img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            img.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        } else {
            img = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(items.get(arg0),
                "drawable", context.getPackageName());

        loadBitmap(resId, img);

        return img;
    }

    public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
        if (cancelPotentialWork(resId, imageView)) {
            final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.empty_photo);
            task.execute(resId);
        }
    }

    static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
        private final WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask> bitmapWorkerTaskReference;

        public AsyncDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap,
                BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask) {
            super(res, bitmap);
            bitmapWorkerTaskReference = new WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask>(
                    bitmapWorkerTask);
        }

        public BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask() {
            return bitmapWorkerTaskReference.get();
        }
    }

    public static boolean cancelPotentialWork(int data, ImageView imageView) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);

        if (bitmapWorkerTask != null) {
            final int bitmapData = bitmapWorkerTask.data;
            if (bitmapData != data) {
                // Cancel previous task
                bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);
            } else {
                // The same work is already in progress
                return false;
            }
        }
        // No task associated with the ImageView, or an existing task was
        // cancelled
        return true;
    }

    private static BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        if (imageView != null) {
            final Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
            if (drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
                final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = (AsyncDrawable) drawable;
                return asyncDrawable.getBitmapWorkerTask();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
            mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
        return (Bitmap) mMemoryCache.get(key);
    }

    class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
        public int data = 0;
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
            // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage
            // collected
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            data = params[0];
            final Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                    context.getResources(), data, 100, 100);
            addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(params[0]), bitmap);
            return bitmap;
        }

        // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
            int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
            // width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
            // guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

}
```

**logcat**

```
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.coderzheaven.testlistview.ListAdapter$1
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at com.coderzheaven.testlistview.ListAdapter.<init>(ListAdapter.java:38)
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at com.coderzheaven.testlistview.MainActivity$HttpAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:140)
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at com.coderzheaven.testlistview.MainActivity$HttpAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-14 17:26:53.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android

Comment: `System.exit(0);` must be removed

Comment: is that reason for this exception

Comment: @Raghunandan I think it says ListAdapter  not found

Comment: the reason may be different but you should not use `System.exit(0);` for sure. What is the package name for the ListAdapter?

Comment: @Raghunandan any other suggestions ?

Comment: @ДмитрийИвановичМенделеев What is `ListAdapter.java` line 38

Comment: @Raghunandan which is an adapter for the grid

Comment: what is on line 38 in `ListAdapter.java`.

Comment: @Raghunandan I think it is a cache to store image and its path

Comment: @Raghunandan i found it from `http://www.coderzheaven.com/tag/faster-loading-images-in-gridviews-or-listviews-in-android-using-menory-caching/`

Comment: ok what is the package name?

Comment: @Raghunandan com.coderzheaven.testlistview

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52683/discussion-between-raghunandan-and---)