# Android/Java Error: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I am building an Android app. I have one project that is MyAndroid project. I have another project called MyModel. I define my data classes (like User) in MyModel.

When I try to create a new user in *MyAndroid* project, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I have included MyModel in *Java Build Path > Projects*, and everything looks great at design time and compile time. But I get the error at runtime.

I am using Eclipse Kepler. I am using the Google Nexus emulator.

I assume I am missing some setting where I need to "reference" the MyModel project properly, so that the MyModel code gets built and deployed along with the MyAndroid project, to the emulator. However, I can't figure out how to do that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this class listed in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: is it a maven or gradle or native project ? Can you share some code also

Comment: The User class? No, not in the manifest. I didn't know I need to do that. How do I reference it in the Manifest? Do I reference each class in MyModel? Or, ..?

Comment: I am not using Maven or Gradle - don't know what those are. I created an android project from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

[I found the answer here on Stack Overflow!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12702315/512761)

I had to go into the build path properties and then go to the ORder tab, and check mark the MyModel project...