# Android app runs using eclipse but not when exported to an apk

Tags: android, eclipse

My android app runs fine using eclipse but not when exported to an apk it gives me the following error when I try to run the app:

```
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554): Process: ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client, PID: 20554
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client/ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
11-26 11:47:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(20554):    ... 11 more
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
    <service
        android:name="com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".development.SensorDisplayActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:exported="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".prefs.SettingsActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".prompting.PromptActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".development.DeveloperActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_developer" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".development.StatusDisplayActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_developer" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".development.ShowErrorLogActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_developer" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".error.ErrorActivity"
        android:exported="false" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MainService" />
    <service android:name=".monitoring.MonitoringService" />
    <service android:name=".writing.EventsLoggingService" />

    <receiver android:name=".BootAndShutdownReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".progress.OnNewDayReceiver" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".calendar.CalendarReceiver" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".progress.ProgressReceiver" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".prompting.SnoozeReceiver" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".progress.HourlyReceiver" >
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".PasswordActivity"
        android:label="" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PasswordActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".tabs.TabActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tab" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TabActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".camera.CameraActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_camera" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CameraActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".calendar.CalendarActivity"
        android:label="Calendar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".calendar.CalendarNotificationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_calendar_notification"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".summary.SummaryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_summary" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Make sure that your MainActivity is not in another package, if it is you should add the package to the android:name

Comment: 1)Make sure you export all libs in properties/java build path/order and export
2)Check your prodguard options, it may mangle class names for third-side libs so they cannot be found

Comment: Thank you, MainActivity is in ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client so I don't think that is the issue.  I will check the libs and prodguard options

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should ensure your `MainActvity.java` is `ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client.MainActivity` and not in *another* package. When you specified the package name in the manifest and defined `.MainActivity`, it attempted to resolve   `MainActivity` as the above. Should your *actual* package containing `MainActvity` be different, you will need to rename the `.MainActivity` and other activities in the manifest to the FULL package name of the Activity.

Alternatively, a `ClassNotFoundException` may occur when exporting if your app uses `progaurd`. You should check your progaurd settings found in `proguard-project.txt`, as it could be obfuscating your application.

Comment: I'm not using proguard so I don't think that's it. My MainActivity class is in the package ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client so I think this is fine as well.  However what gets me is this line : ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client/ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client.MainActivity   Any ideas why it would think the path to MainActivity is ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client/ca.uwaterloo.kin.rehabmonitor.client.MainActivity ?

Comment: Possibly try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android

Comment: Thanks, there seem to be quite a few things I can try there. None of them have worked so far but it's a start