# Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, gradle, build.gradle

I'm getting this error executing my Android app (I cleaned it and then built it, but the error is still present)

- Sync: OK
- Make Project: OK
- Clean: OK
- Run: Error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' .com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.rzr.rzevallosr.miappdepruebas"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

// This library handles authentication and authorization
compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-auth:1.0.0-beta9@aar'
// This library handles music playback
compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player:1.0.0-beta9@aar'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'

compile files('libs/spotify-web-api-android-master-0.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/okio-1.3.0.jar')
}
```

EDIT: I didn't see "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])" it was compiling twice my libraries, so i just comment:

```
//compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
//compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
//compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'

//compile files('libs/spotify-web-api-android-master-0.1.0.jar')
//compile files('libs/okio-1.3.0.jar')
```

and it works fine.

Comment: @JaredBurrows The issue in my case was that my app was compiling twice the libraries .. one on "compile fileTree" (compiles all your libs directory) and "compile ****".

Comment: Can you please post an answer and mark it correct?

Comment: please check out my post here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33387368/740372

Comment: I am having the same error but my gradle file does not have so many compiles. Please Help. I posted this question :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558251/java-exe-error-while-building-project-in-android-studio?noredirect=1#comment56859897_34558251

I am completely new to android development.

Comment: I had this issue because I had a java package and file identical to a package and file in a dependency.

Comment: Have a look at my comment below, I had the same error and my case was nothing related to MultiDex, it's just about JRE location

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I didn't know (by then) that **"compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])"** compile all that has jar extension on libs folder, so i just comment (or delete) this lines:

```
//compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
//compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
//compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'

//compile files('libs/spotify-web-api-android-master-0.1.0.jar')
//compile files('libs/okio-1.3.0.jar')
```

and it works fine. Thanks anyway! My bad.

Comment: or the other way around: comment `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` in gradle. It has helped me.

Comment: is there any other solution regarding this issue? i didn't compile each jar file but instead just used this line `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` but it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 204):

This issue is quite possibly due to exceeding the 65K methods dex limit imposed by Android. This problem can be solved either by cleaning the project, and removing some unused libraries and methods from dependencies in build.gradle, **OR** by adding multidex support.

**So, If you have to keep libraries and methods, then you can enable multi dex support by declaring it in the gradle config.**

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

You can read more about multidex support and developing [apps with more than 65K methods here](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/building/multidex.html).

Comment: And after that override the method in startup class:

@Override protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) { super.attachBaseContext(base); MultiDex.install(this); }

Comment: If you want to see what exactly is causing the error, try building your project via gradle terminal, like this `./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace --debug` . I've seen this error in my case `com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
`

Answer (score 93):

For me the problem was, i had put a unnecessary complie library code in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

which was causing over 65k methods, so removed it,gradle sync, cleaned project, and then ran again and then this error stopped.
I needed just maps and gcm so i put these lines and synced project

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
```

Hi people i again encountered this problem and this time it was because of changing build tools version and it really required me to enable multidex..so i added these my app's build.gradle file..

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.am.android"
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 23
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    jumboMode = true
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

And create a class that extends Application class and include this method inside the class..

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

also include in OnCreate method too

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    MultiDex.install(this);
    super.onCreate();
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution, you should only include the libraries you're actually using.

Comment: works for me!! change "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'"  to compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0"

Comment: Nice one, also refer to: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup - provide a list of various individual libraries.

Comment: @edsappfactory.com i referred that , used and modified.

Answer (score 32):

Just in case if someone still struggling with this and have no clue why is this happening and how to fix. In fact this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_xx\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

can have many reasons to happen but certainly not something related to your JDK version so don't wast your time in wrong direction.
These are two main reasons for this to happen

1. You have same library or jar file included several places and some of them conflicting with each other.
2. You are about to or already exceeded 65k method limit

First case can be fixed as follows:
Find out which dependencies you have included multiple times. In order to do this run following command in android studio terminal

```
gradlew -q dependencies yourProjectName_usually_app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

this will return all the dependencies but jar files that you include from lib folder
try to get rid of duplication marked with asterisk (*), this is not always possible but in some cases you still can do it, after this try to exclude modules that are included many times, you can do it like this

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

---

For the second case when you exceeding method limit suggestion is to try to minimize it by removing included libraries (note sounds like first solution) if no way to do it add multiDexEnabled true to your defaultConfig

```
defaultConfig {
   ...
   ...
   multiDexEnabled true
}
```

this increases method limit but it is not the best thing to do because of possible performance issues
**IMPORTANT** adding only `multiDexEnabled true` to `defaultConfig` is not enough in fact on all devices running android <5 Lollipop it will result in unexpected behavior and `NoClassDefFoundError`. how to solve it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28951863/855843)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and I fixed removing the library that were unnecessary

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

I removed that library and I could run the project without any problem.

Comment: I was trying to add the slidingMenu class and removing this from my main gradle worked for me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

Mine got solved by enabling multiDex for debug builds.

```
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I Reject Embedded JDK ( in 32bit ) because embedded **JDK is 64bit**

Right click your Project -> **Open Module Setting** -> ***SDK Location*** -> Uncheck Use embedded JDk then set your JDK Path, eg in Ubuntu **/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386**

Comment: I think this works because embedded JDK is 64bit. I had same problem on my 32bit machine.

Comment: This fixed the issue on my 32-bit machine. `echo $JAVA_HOME` for the path

Comment: Yes, I knew it had to do with my machine being 32-bit. Thank you, Zacharia -- saved my day!

Answer (score 5):

Possible problem: You have exceeded dex 65k methods limit, may be you added some library or several methods before problem occurred?

Comment: Not several .. just a couple of methods.

Comment: Hm, try to build previous version of project or remove unused library(ies) if it's possible and do rebuild

Comment: I have just a few methods too

Answer (score 3):

If You have already updated your SDK and You also using google-play-services then you need to take care of the dependency because there are some kind of conflics with :

Follow the below : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' Replace by compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

Note: Here '6.5.87' is the google-play-service version. I hope it will help..

Answer (score 2):

> I think it's conflicts of .jar file in your project.

I have removed android-support-v4.jar from libs folder and its working !!!

if your project gives error, check in your build.gradle file

> dependencies {
>
> }

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was that the new library (gradle dependency) that I had added was relying on some other dependencies and two of those underlying dependencies were conflicting/clashing with some dependencies of other libraries/dependencies in my build script. Specifically, I added Apache Commons `Validator` (for email validation), and two of its dependencies (Apache Commons `Logging` and Apache Commons `Collections`) were conflicting with those used by Robolectric (because different versions of same libraries were present in my build path). So I excluded those conflicting versions of dependencies (`modules`) when adding the new dependency (the `Validator`):

```
compile ('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1') {
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'commons-collections'
}
```

You can see the dependencies of your gradle module(s) (you might have only one module in your project) using the following gradle command (I use the gradle wrapper that gets created for you if you have created your project in Android Studio/Intellij Idea). Run this command in your project's root directory:

./gradlew :YOUR-MODULE-NAME:dependencies

After adding those `exclude` directives and retrying to run, I got a `duplicate file` error for `NOTICE.txt`that is used by some apache commons libraries like Logging and Collections. I had to exclude that text file when packaging. In my build.gradle, I added:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

It turned out that the new library (the `Validator`) can work with slightly older versions of its dependencies/modules (which are already imported into my build path by another library (Robolectric)). This was the case with this specific library, but other libraries might be using the latest API of the underlying dependencies (in which case you have to try to see if the other libraries that rely on the conflicting module/dependency are able to work with the newer version (by excluding the older version of the module/dependecy under those libraries's entries)).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got this error when there are 2 or more libraries conflict (same library but different versions). Check your app build.gradle in dependencies block.

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternatives that'll work for sure:

1. Clean your project and then build.

If the above method didn't worked, try the next.

2. Add the following to build.gradle file at app level

   ```
   defaultConfig {   

   multiDexEnabled true

   }
   ```

Comment: i tried both, but i have a new error `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/view/MotionEventCompatEclair.class` , what should i do next?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168063/gradle-duplicate-entry-java-util-zip-zipexception

Comment: this error is occurring because of duplicate/same packages in your project

Answer (score 1):

Updating my Java SDK to the latest version `1.7.0_79` and updating the `SDK Location` under `Project Structure` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that apart from having

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.X.X_XX.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 2

I had this trace as well:

> Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   already added: Lcom/mypackage/ClassX;

The problem was that I was adding the same class in two differents libraries. Removing the class/jar file from one of the libraries, the project run properly

Comment: Exactly, I got same problem, same class signature, fortunately it was my class so I refactored it. I wrote answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35045501/3397345

Answer (score 1):

For me i was adding the whole playstore dependencies

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

But i needed google map only , so i made it more specific and the error was resolved.

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'

Answer (score 0):

in my case problem was build tools version which was **23.0.0 rc3** and i changed to 22.0.1 and my problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using a low quality cable/defected cable to connect your device to the PC, I replaced the cable and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of using more number of libraries.in my case 'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-9.4.0' caused this error.To avoid this error use necessary libraries.for example if you want to use Maps in your app.Then use 
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'.while adding google play services dependency specify the needed libraries only.by default it includes all the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In Your `gradle.build` file, Use this

```
"compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])"
```

And it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what exactly is causing the error, try building your project via gradle terminal, like this `./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace --debug` . I've seen the following error in my case `com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536`

This happened when I was trying to entegrate Google Maps to my project. To fix it, I simply checked libraries I was including

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'`

I simply changed it to

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'`

and problem was gone

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after converting my project to `Kotlin`. My problem was that my jre location was changed to an invalid path during the process (I wonder why this could happen... made me waste time). Fixed it by doing this:

```
File > Project Structure > SDK Location
```

Unchecked the `Use embedded JDK` option, which was pointing to an old JDK installation, and selected the correct one:

```
/home/my_user/jdk1.8.0_101
```

After changing this, the error disappeared

Answer (score 0):

**WORKED FOR ME :)**

i upgraded the java to the latest version 8 previously it was 7  and then go to **OPEN MODULE SETTING right clicking on proj**ect and **changed the jdk path to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle** the new java 8 installed. And restart the studio

check in /usr/lib/jvm for java 8 folder name

I am using ubuntu[image]