# ProcessException: ExecException: Process 'command ' /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Content/Home/bin/java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting exception:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

after i updated the Google Play services to `7.5.0` as:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

but if i change it back to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

everything is working fine, i am also facing the same problem if i add Google Cloud Backend Module in my project.

Comment: this happen when you add jar file to libs folder & same you compile in gradle using gradle dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).
More specifically at the "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable" section [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split).

By using com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0, you are compiling with all Google Play services APIs.
You should use the Google Play services APIs that you need.

For example, if you need Google+, then you use, com.google.android.gms:play-services-**plus**:7.5.0

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this trace as well:

> Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   already added: Lcom/mypackage/ClassX;

The problem was that I was adding the same class in two differents libraries. Removing the class/jar file from one of the libraries, the project run properly

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34996864/2390685