# android studio project complies fine but making error before running on device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-import

My android studio project giving following error right before it runs on device while it compiles error free,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexCustomerDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Followed many links but no luck any solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to examine the whole gradle/build log, as the error is somewhere up there and it's easy to overlook. I had this error when I tried to include bad version of Scala (compiled for Java 8, which is not supported by Android).

Comment: Please post the full output from the *Gradle Console* (View→Tool Windows→Gradle Console)

Comment: you need to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544114/processexception-execexception-process-command-library-java-javavirtualmac) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544114/processexception-execexception-process-command-library-java-javavirtualmac)