# Android Studio application running issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an android application which was originally built on Eclipse IDE along with ADT. When the new FB SDK 4+ came out, the app was upgraded to use the new FB SDK in Eclipse only. It was running fine. Now, I wanted to import the application in Android Studio. I had imported it successfully and it executed as expected using the new FB Library as a module.

Now, I wanted to change the FB library referencing in the way gradle does in Android Studio. I have followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myWu-q8Q2NA) and [this article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) for achieving the goal. After following the steps, I have removed the FB modules from my project. The project shows no other error, but whenever I try to run it, I get an error like:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':xxxx xxxx:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I am unsure about what is causing this error, I have cleaned the project and also tried to rebuild it, but it did not help. This is the only error I can see in the console.

The build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile project(':Viewpage:viewpage-library')
        compile project(':CountryPicker')
        compile project(':google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
        compile project(':numberpicker-library')
        compile project(':numberpicker-library')
        compile project(':CountryPicker')
        compile project(':Viewpage:viewpage-library')
        compile project(':google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Why I am getting the above mentioned error while running the app?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle

Comment: @sasikumar y issue does not seem to match the conditions in the discussions on that page, do you want me to look at anyone of them particularly?

Comment: why are you compiling/adding libraries 2 times?

Comment: @Shvet I have removed those repetitions, it was all there after importing in Android Studio, but even after removing the repeats, its of no use, the error still persists.