# Getting Multiple dex error when using render script support lib

Tags: android, android-support-library, renderscript

I am using render script in support library in my gradle file.

```
  renderscriptTargetApi 22
  renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

After I added these 2 lines, I am getting this error

```
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:    
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program       
 Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had similar issue. Try add to your gradle file

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

just to be sure you are not exceeding the 65K methods dex limit imposed by Android ([Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle)). If you are using some other android-support libraries like appcompat or design or support-v4/v7... add another line to your gradle file

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

Renderscript library already includes support-annotations library, which then may collide with those other support libraries, I suppose. Anyway, these gradle commands fixed it for me.

**Edit:** It was supposedly fixed in 23.1.0 revisions of Android support libraries, therefore after updating to 23.1.0 you'd need to remove that all*.exclude command. Otherwise your app would not compile due to missing support-annotations library.

Answer (score 2):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181697 is the bug for this, along with a temporary workaround.

Comment: The solution is to manually delete the annotation classes in jar. I am using android studio and those libraries are located in "External Libraries".  How to delete those classes in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

```
  dexOptions {
  preDexLibraries = false
}
```

In your build.gradle file try adding the following block inside your android block.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 renderscriptTargetApi 18
 renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

Comment: This requires that your minimum sdk version (minSdkVersion) be 18 as well. This did not work for me since I require minSdkVersion 17.