# Using buildToolsVersion 23 fails because Multiple dex files define 'AnimRes'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

Before you claim ***DUPLICATE*** please read the question.

This only occurs with the latest version of the build tools. Older versions do not display this problem. I've already tried the solutions offered on other questions here for multiple definitions of `@AnimRes`. None have helped so far, which is why I posted a new question. Same symptoms, different cause, different solution.

I can build without problem when using `buildToolsVersion 22.0.1`, but when I switch to `buildToolsVersion 23` the build fails with error

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple
>   dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

This is a list of my dependencies:

```
provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.5.0'
compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.6'
compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0'
compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.10.10'
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.2'
compile 'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.12'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
```

To ensure everyone (including Espresso) uses the same version of the `support-annotations` I have the following in my build file:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
}
```

Removing this will cause other failures.

Is this a possible bug in the build tools or am I doing something wrong?
I've tried setting `Incremental false` in `dexOptions`. It didn't help.

Using `./gradlew -q app:dependencies` I get the following:

```
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0
+--- com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
+--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
+--- com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.+ -> 23.0.0 (*)
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4
+--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
+--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1
+--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.8
+--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0 -> 1.5.0
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.5.0
+--- com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.6
+--- com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1
+--- com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 23.0.0
+--- com.nispok:snackbar:2.10.10
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0 -> 23.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0 -> 23.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0 -> 23.0.0
+--- com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.2
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0 -> 22.0.0 (*)
+--- in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.12
\--- de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0
```

Comment: "the build fails with error" -- there should be more information in the Gradle Console about where the duplicates are coming from.

Comment: It doesn't say which entities define `@AnimRes`. I'm now forcing all support libs to use `23.0.0` and still failing the same way.

Comment: What CommonsWare is saying is that you shall see more information if you run gradle from the console (i.e. `gradlew assembleDebug`).

Comment: That's what I'm doing. That's how I ended up with the pretty graph above. I've updated the post to show the rest of the error message (including the stack trace)

Comment: This looks like a bug in renderscript-v8. The `renderscript-v8.jar` version included in `22.0.1` build tools does not contain any annotations, but the jar included in `23.0.0` includes these annotations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Update***: This is fixed in the 23.0.1 version of build tools as the `support` directory is no longer included in `renderscript-v8.jar`

The culprit is the version of `renderscript-v8.jar` that is included in the build tools.

I think this `tree` output tells everything:

```
C:.
├───renderscript-v8-22.0.01
│   ├───android
│   │   └───support
│   │       └───v8
│   │           └───renderscript
│   └───META-INF
└───renderscript-v8-23
    ├───android
    │   └───support
    │  ***  ├───annotation
    │       └───v8
    │           └───renderscript
    └───META-INF
```

I've tagged the directories with the version of the build tools that included them. Notice the `annotations` subdirectory in `renderscript-v8-23` that doesn't exist in `renderscript-v8-22.0.01`.

There is already a report of the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179493
And a duplicate here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181697

Answer (score 6):

I can't say I understand this solution - or that it's necessarily a good fix, but it got my app compiling again:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

Also, see: [Getting Multiple dex error when using render script support lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051938/getting-multiple-dex-error-when-using-render-script-support-lib/32090710#32090710)

Credit to Luboš Staráček for this solution