# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION when using renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Hi i previously using **renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true** whiteout  any problem but today when i want to run my app i giving this error message

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

i even create new empty sample project with no dependency but same error message here is my .gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mk.sample"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I understand this solution - or that it's necessarily a good fix, but it got my app compiling again:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

Also, see: [Getting Multiple dex error when using render script support lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051938/getting-multiple-dex-error-when-using-render-script-support-lib/32090710#32090710)

and [Using buildToolsVersion 23 fails because Multiple dex files define 'AnimRes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080309/using-buildtoolsversion-23-fails-because-multiple-dex-files-define-animres)

Credit to Luboš Staráček for this solution