# ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix: setAdd method is not implemented in support library

Tags: android, renderscript, colormatrix, android-renderscript

Here is my question:
I'm working with real time image processing, so I want to use ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix instead of regular ColorMatrix (cause it's much faster)

**android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix (API level 19)** has method **setAdd**

```
void    setAdd(float r, float g, float b, float a)
void    setAdd(Float4 f)
Set the value to be added after the color matrix has been applied.
```

its parameters has the same meaning as (e, j, o, t) in ColorMatrix formula

```
   R’ = a*R + b*G + c*B + d*A + e;
   G’ = f*R + g*G + h*B + i*A + j;
   B’ = k*R + l*G + m*B + n*A + o;
   A’ = p*R + q*G + r*B + s*A + t;
```

My min SDK version is 14, so I've got to use **android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix** from support library. 

Unfortunately it doesn't have these **setAdd** methods. And I can't find a workaround for them.

Did anybody have deal with that problem? Is it possible to fully cover ColorMatrix features with render script Instrinsic from support library or should I write my own custom RenderScript?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v8/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix.html#setAdd(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)

Comment: Well... I checked things twice and found that setAdd was added only to build tool 23.0.0 (Which has bug related to render script :) ) in 21.0.1 these methods are absent. Anyway, thanks you a lot, your comment pointed me in right direction

Comment: By the way, build tool 23.0.0 defect is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080309/using-buildtoolsversion-23-fails-because-multiple-dex-files-define-animres

Comment: what does support library version have to do with build tool version? do i miss something?

Comment: Real path to the imported class looks like this: C:\Users\VinSmile\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\22.0.1\renderscript\lib\renderscript-v8.jar!\android\support\v8\renderscript\ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, possible solution (thanks to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) for advising):

1) Change build tool version to 23.0.0 (it won't compile at this point due to [defect in this build tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080309/using-buildtoolsversion-23-fails-because-multiple-dex-files-define-animres))

2) Try workaround from [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32162751/1864364)

3) Profit

I've just tested it, and it works. Hope android will fix this defect soon