# Android Studio not compiling project after adding RenderScript API in build.gradle file

Tags: java, android, renderscript

I am trying to use RenderScript API in Android Studio. I added this two line in the build.gradle file as mentioned in official android developer site:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.aaa111.androidrnd"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 16

    renderscriptTargetApi 22
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
  }
```

After adding this i get the following error when i tried to run :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I am using Android Studio 1.3.2 version.

Comment: Can you check your libs any duplicate files are there?

Comment: In libs there are nothing even after i synchronized the gradle.

Comment: Hi, check my answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051938/getting-multiple-dex-error-when-using-render-script-support-lib/32090710#32090710

Comment: Thanks Lubos its worked. :)