# Android Studio / cannot resolve getDefaultProguardFile

Tags: android

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

**OR**

You can try **File** **->** **Invalidate Caches/Restart**, and select this option to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i did not get how to change, the code you showed to me is same as mine?

Answer (score 3):

Just update your **buildTypes** instead your .

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Then **Clean - Rebuild** And 
**File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart** . I hope it will helps you .

**FYI** : I think your gradle file under `" apply plugin: 'com.android.application'"`

Comment: Thanks for reply but Clean - Rebuild And File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart  it did not solve the problem. 

 The following is the error


Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: @Meli http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle