# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: java, android

"com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2"

build.gradle(using Android Studio)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.com.notifdemo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
        compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2"
    }
```

Comment: It can be a duplication libraries problem. Try to remove the duplication.

Comment: Don't include the entire play-services library, it is huge and can cause dex errors because it goes over the class limit or something

Comment: Please check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle

Comment: I m not using entire _play-services_ , using just **Google-messaging-services**.
And please tell me where i m duplicating the libraries.
Is it the issue of "getDefaultProguardFile" because it shows in red "underline".
Thanks for reply