# Error:Execution failed for task: ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('poi-3.13-beta1-20150723.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Please ask a question, from your error we can't find your problem. Thank you.

Comment: This duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally crack the solution this error was occurring because my code was exceeding max-limit. I fount an useful link to solve this: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 1):

When you face this kind of problem like
**'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe' finished with non-zero exit value 2**

It means you need to verify all the dependencies, manifests and the modules you have attached to the project. The problem is now due to any update or any of the reason their is some problem in any the file code

Possible reason:-

- Minimum SDK version is too low
- Any of resource file issue
- Any of manifest is showing any error
- You declared multiple Launch Activity
- You may need to enable MultiDex now

In short, just go through all files and try to find the issue with Project or Modules.

Best approach : Clean Project, Rebuild Project, Synchronize and try to install application.

(Any of the above step may show you an error in any of your file which is actually causing this problem)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was solved, when I deleted **jar** file in **/app/libs** folder, because **library** was also declared in **/app/buld.gradle**