# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'. in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I am run my application in android studio error. I am new in android developing.

My Logtag is here:

```
        Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
    Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
    > Could not find com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7//recyclerview-v7-.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7//recyclerview-v7-.jar
         file:/C:/Users/ANDROID/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7//recyclerview-v7-.pom
         file:/C:/Users/ANDROID/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7//recyclerview-v7-.jar
         file:/C:/Users/ANDROID/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7//recyclerview-v7-.pom
         file:/C:/Users/ANDROID/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7//recyclerview-v7-.jar
     Required by:
         ShoppingMazza:app:unspecified
    Information:BUILD FAILED
    Information:Total time: 4.964 secs
    Information:1 error
    Information:0 warnings
    Information:See complete output in console
```

My `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.catalyst.android.shoppingmazza"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:'
}
```

Comment: Please add your gradle file here.

Comment: I added my gradle file

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:'  Add the version

Comment: I tried but no profit

Comment: @AnandJain have u resolved ur issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Error:**

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.   Could not
>   resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:.

From error i can say you'll have to add the following gradle dependency :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

**EDIT:**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. >
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

For this error i think you are compiling `JAR` library twice. You are using

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

in `build.gradle` file so it will compile all library that has jar extension on libs folder, so You can remove this lines:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
```

If issue still exists then issue is quite possibly due to exceeding the 65K methods dex limit imposed by Android. This problem can be solved either by cleaning the project, and removing some unused libraries and methods from dependencies in `build.gradle`, OR by adding `multidex` support.

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: After adding this line the error come:- Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: which is your compileSDK and targetSDK version?

Comment: My minSdkVersion 16 and targetSdkVersion 23 and compileSdkVersion 23

Comment: do you have latest support library installed?

Comment: Yes I have lastest support library installled

Comment: did u try multiDexEnabled true?

Comment: for this issue you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle

Comment: clean project and build again then try

Comment: which gradle version you are using?

Comment: versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0"

Comment: no not that version. there is another build.gradle file in your project in which gradle version is there

Comment: can you tell me where is another gradle file

Comment: in project main direcotry not in app directory

Comment: Ohh Thanks 2.4 is my gradle version

Comment: can try to build project with 1.3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget the version? In your gradle config you should have something like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
```

Comment: After adding this line the error come:- Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 –

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I deleted `caches` folder inside `.gradle` folder and then I added `compile`. It worked for me!