# Gradle Building Errors

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

I've been receiving the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.>
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 2

This is my current dependency. I have been trying to figure out how to resolve this error but I just can not figure it out. Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vokanovich.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ("com.magnet.mmx:magnet-mmx-client-android:1.9.1@aar") {
    transitive=true
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.3.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

And this is my other build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "https://repo.magnet.com/artifactory/public"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/33099224/3702862?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle) link may solve your problem .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31759781/1371041 Resolved it for me. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that it exceeded 65k methods. It was resolved by applying the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31759781/1371041

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Just write inside defaultConfig in **build.gradle**

    `defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }`

Hope this help you!)

Comment: It is always recommended to reduce unused library code rather than using multiDexEnabled. If that doesn't resolve it, then you should use multiDexEnabled as your last resort.