# establishing parse connection with a sample android activity. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

hi i am trying to establish a connection with parse.com i am new to android programming and i have issues with building the gradle.

i tried various trouble shooting methods but in vain.

i got to know may be because i might be using two libraries the problem may arise . but in fact i included only

ONE PARSE-1.10.3 .jar file. in the library folder

i followed the instructions of this [gentleman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KQN_W9AGlU) though the voice not being clear, he was clear enough to follow his guidelines.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'   
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bandi_parc.example.android.parseconnectiontest_v2"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

 ***multiDexEnabled true***
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}    
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile project(':Parse-1.10.3')    
}    

dependencies {
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle) answer in stackoverflow i included 
`multiDexEnabled true`

resulting in this error now.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class

please help regarding my issue on how to solve my problem and connect to parse.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're including Parse library two times:

```
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
compile project(':Parse-1.10.3')
```

You should remove one of them (I'll remove the local one, i.e. `compile project(':Parse-1.10.3')`)

**Edit**: In fact, you should have a single `dependencies` block, with all of them inside (and, as I said, only one reference to Parse library).

Also, about `multiDexEnabled true`, you should only enable it if you *absolutely* need it. For more information see here: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: dude i found that if i use two libraries there would be a conflict and i wont be able to compile properly. therefore i am using this code now which does not give any gradle error:

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], exclude: 'android-support-v4.jar',dir:     'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile project(':Parse-1.10.3')
    }

but now i get an error : Error:(26, 36) error: cannot access Task
class file for bolts.Task not found

this error is from 
    
    testObject.saveInBackground();
the code is taken from quickstart SDK to test

Comment: the code with no err:

    dependencies{ compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], exclude: 'android-support-v4.jar',dir: 'libs') compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' compile project(':Parse-1.10.3') }

Answer (score 0):

i have found an answer to my plight :

and here is the gist of code which i used to resolve it.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], exclude: 'android-support-v4.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile project(':Parse-1.10.3')
compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.1.jar')
}
```

adding parse library and the bolts library without creating a conflict between the present android support libraries. thank you @xavier and thankyou stackoverflow.