# Android studio parse getting gradle error

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, build.gradle

I have just added parse to my Android Aplication and now i can't run the app
i keep getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

i have tried to increase the heap size in the build.gradle with:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

but it still won't run

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.hadi.do2get"
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 22
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
multiDexEnabled true
}
packagingOptions {
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}
dexOptions {
preDexLibraries = false
javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}



dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

How do i fix it?

Comment: I removed my answer to prevent it to prevent the other users to come and answer your question. I'll give more help after you put the gradle file :)

Comment: ok i have put it now

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: run gradlew assemble --info to get the full stacktrace and post there

Answer (score 0):

Did you put

```
defaultConfig {
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

in the `android {` tag?

**EDIT**

Following those two links:

[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561153/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug)

[Android Studio: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787747/android-studio-errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug)

It seems that you are including a same library several time. You can try to remove the lines after `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` one by one until you find the redundant include.

Comment: Yes, i will put my build.gradle file here

Comment: I have tried to delete them one by one but i still get errors
I can't delete the last two lines:
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
because i got them from parse so i have to write them in the build.gradle file

Comment: When i compile my application with the build.gradle file that is in here i get the error:

    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class

Comment: Look there, thats the exact same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254883/establishing-parse-connection-with-a-sample-android-activity-errorexecution-fa    and it seems that its actually linked with a redundant compile I was talking about

Comment: I have looked at it, but i im not including two parse libaries like the one in the link

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
```

with

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the file, you need to add the dependencies to the another `build.gradle` file in the gradle folder

Comment: It is wrong. You can add the dependencies in the build.gradle of the module.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the bolt-task.jar files were missing so i just had to import the bolt-task jar files to my libs folder in thhe project.........

[image]