# Error compilng build.gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I was trying to compile

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

on my gradle project, but when I'm trying to run it, error and the log say that :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':thingNote:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This issue is quite possibly due to exceeding the 65K methods dex limit imposed by Android." -- @minhazur

Check out this other post [HERE...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle)