# Android - finished with non-zero exit value 2 android studio

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to use Parse as part of my Android app and getting this error when trying to run the project in Debug.

Here is my **Gradle file**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "david.todolist"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="david.todolist"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<receiver android:name=".ReminderNotification">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action." />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListNodeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list_node"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="david.todolist.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Signup_Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CreateTeam"
        android:label="Create new task team"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".InviteMember"
        android:label="Invite Members Your Team"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login_activity"
        android:label="Login to Wiggle"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".EditTaskActivity"
        android:label="Edit Task"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".select_location"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_select_location"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="APPLICATION_ID" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
        android:value="CLIENT_KEY" />

</application>
```

Content of **Libs** folder:
[image]

**Console output**:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":

[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/AbstractQueryController$1;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.585 secs
```

How can I resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "finished with non-zero exit value 2 android studio" -- you are seeing this in the Gradle Console window. Look higher in the console output to see the source of this message.

Comment: This is all great info, but where is the error log?

Comment: in logcat, the error should be in red. Please read about logs in Android studio

Comment: read also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle

Comment: @piotrek1543, I've read this before posting. Placed the 'defaultConfig' tag and the issue remained.
Will check and post Console logs.

Comment: try `file -> invalidate caches`

Comment: @piotrek1543, Tried to 'invalidate caches' did not help.
Added console output.

Comment: add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` and `multiDexEnabled true` to your `build.gradle` like here (and then rebuild): http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: @piotrek1543
Getting this error:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class