# I am getting ****finished with non-zero exit value 2. how to resolve it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have read many questions related to this problem but all of them pointing to same solution jar duplicate in dependencies. I have check my dependencies their is no duplicate jar please tell how should i resolve this issue

**

```
"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2"
```

**

here's my dependencies files

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile files('libs/nextomeframework_beta1_mod.jar')
        compile 'gov.nist.math:jama:1.0.3'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.3'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
        compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.1'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.1'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.1'
        compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:core:0.26'
        compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.3'
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
        compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
        compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.8.5'
        compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.8.5'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
        compile files('libs/concurrent.jar')
        compile files('libs/Jama-1.0.3.jar')
        compile files('libs/zip4j_1.3.2.jar')
```

Comment: obviously you should decide if you wana add all jars from libs dir with `compile fileTree(...)` or selected one with `compile files('libs/...)` ... obviously using both will ends with adding the library twice

Comment: Not all of them, this is the first result on Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle

Comment: Maybe a Multidex issue. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30692005/2960788

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a duplication in `jama` library as you have mentioned

`compile 'gov.nist.math:jama:1.0.3'`

and

`compile files('libs/Jama-1.0.3.jar')`

Try removing one of them.