# Android app won't launch because of Gradle issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

i am trying to compile my android project using my Samsung/Virtual machine , but i am getting the following error:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:         
    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
    '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' 
    finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

i couldn't find an answer anywhere, any thoughts please ?

Comment: What are the libraries you're using?

Answer (score 0):

**Try enabling multi dex file support in you gradle.**

Add below code to your `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this error isn't related to JDK or gradle itself, and could have many reasons such as:

1. **Exceeding 65k method limit.**

You could try enabling multi dex support in gradle:

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Or just try to minimize application by removing some unnecessary libraries.

2. **Some jar or library file is included in several places.**

For this run following command in Android Studio:

```
gradlew -q dependencies yourProjectName_usually_app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

Search for duplications in listed dependences (marked with asterisk *) and remove it.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle) question there are more possibilities listed.

Answer (score 0):

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' -> Should be 1.3.1

buildToolsVersion '23.0.0' -> Should be '23.0.2'
```

Also add

```
 defaultConfig {        
// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
```

}

clean your code and build again

Comment: its great ! but my grade version is currently 1.1.0, how can i update it ?

Comment: Update your sdk using sdk manager. After that you will get option to change it to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

```
For me the problem was, i had put a unnecessary compile library code in build.gradle

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
which was causing over 65k methods, so removed it,gradle sync, cleaned project, and then ran again and then this error stopped. I needed just maps and gcm so i put these lines and synced project

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'

Hi people i again encountered this problem and this time it was because of changing build tools version and it really required me to enable multidex..so i added these my app's build.gradle file..

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.am.android"
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 23
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    jumboMode = true
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
And create a class that extends Application class and include this method inside the class..

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
also include in OnCreate method too

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    MultiDex.install(this);
    super.onCreate();
}
```