# gcm end points for push notification to android device giving strange error

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

follwing this github project and instruction

[here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints)

I am trying to implement push notification to android device from google back end.
the backend part runs successfully in localhost but when I try to run the android project I get a strange error in build process every time.

[image]Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle

Comment: thanks one of the answers did solve my problem