# finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle

Tags: java, android

Please can anyone help me, I have a problem when I run my android application this error is shown :

```
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`
```

I work with **android studio 1.2.3**

The app build.gradle is this:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hp.scan"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1.2'
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try to restart studio. It happens sometimes due to low RAM

Comment: i restarted, no results.

Comment: Remove same multiple dependancy

Comment: run it with `--stacktrace`

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle

Comment: @user3595578 No-one can help till you post your `gradle`.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna, thank you. You can see the gradle in the answer below

Comment: Add `multiDexEnabled true` as suggested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32400904/5067493) answer.

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya OP has added `gradle` in answer instead.

Comment: @user3595578 use `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1' `  & `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'`Then Add `multiDexEnabled true` then `Clean-Rebuild-Sync`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install a newer version of jdk, remove your current jdk and install a newer one. 
I hope it will help.