# Keep getting error when I try install pushwoosh and compile to android: Cordova

Tags: android, pushwoosh

This is what happens when I install push woosh

```
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat$1;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 1.862 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: /Users/apple/usd/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/apple/usd/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Build Gradle dependencies as requested

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
```

When I uninstall pushwoosh plugin the app works perfectly

Comment: Can you provide a longer/more verbose error message? That command can be run for a lot of things and fail for a ton more

Comment: can you post your dependencies from  bulid.gradle file ?

Comment: Hi as requested I have provided the info :)

Comment: Thank you for your attempt but the answer was what I put, another plugin is conflicting with the pushwoosh plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you use custom `Application` class in your project you should inherit it from `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication` to make multidex work.

Comment: Can you give more detail as to what you mean?

Comment: @KingsleyMitchell did you create any custom `Application` class in Your project which extends `Application`.

Comment: This is a cordova project and there is no application I think?

Comment: @KingsleyMitchell Are you using `Java 1.7` and `1.8`.

Comment: Using jdk1.8.0_91.jdk

Comment: Thank you for your attempt but the answer was what I put, another plugin is conflicting with the pushwoosh plugin

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not hit the dex method count limit. Check out this thread that lists a couple of options to troubleshoot this: [Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle)

Comment: When I put the   multiDexEnabled true then it says my gradle is too low

Comment: Thank you for your attempt but the answer was what I put, another plugin is conflicting with the pushwoosh plugin

Answer (score 0):

Multidex

If you have an issue compiling the app and you're getting an error similar to this (com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define):

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Then at least one other plugin you have installed is using an outdated way to declare dependencies such as android-support or play-services-gcm. This causes gradle to fail, and you'll need to identify which plugin is causing it and request an update to the plugin author, so that it uses the proper way to declare dependencies for cordova. See this for the reference on the cordova plugin specification, it'll be usefull to mention it when creating an issue or requesting that plugin to be updated.

Common plugins to suffer from this outdated dependency management are plugins related to facebook, google+, notifications, crosswalk and google maps.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you have two classes with the same names during the linking (dexer) phase.

```
Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat$1;
```

It looks like other plugin is referencing google play services library directly.

The correct way of referencing it on Cordova is through gradle (as Pushwoosh plugin is doing):
https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin/blob/master/plugin.xml#L102

Find the other plugin who is referencing google-play-services.jar or similar and remove (just delete) this library from there.

Similar issue:
https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin/issues/179#issuecomment-222638452