# Getting errors on Generate Signed APK in Android Studio 2

Tags: android, gradle, apk, signed, generated

When I try to run project it works fine but when i try to generate signed apk i got this error.

I was try to clean project and rebuild it but none of them works for me.

My Problem is not related to duplicate libraries in Build:Gradle

```
> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
> class
>     Error:(edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.locks.FIFOCondVar$1)
> that doesn't come with an
>     Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>     Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>     Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>     Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>     Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>     Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>     Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
>     :PersianCalendar:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED
>     Error:Execution failed for task ':PersianCalendar:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

<br/>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I'm using the latest version of android studio and gradle.

also try build.gradle:

```
lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
  }
```

Comment: have you set dex enable option ?

Comment: No give me sec to try it

Comment: Not working for `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: Are you using proguard ?

Comment: then there may be some rules need to be done in proguard file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle)

Comment: I also try to use `-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontoptimize` in proguard but not effective

Comment: I didnt duplicate any libraries :(( Really dont no whats problem ...