# Execution failed':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.internal.ExecException: Process 'java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-studio, apache-poi

When I tried to add poi-ooxml in app/build.gradle file then this error is coming 
"Execution failed' :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1"

app/build.gradle :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
      compileSdkVersion 23
      buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "applicationID"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
     compile files('libs/jxl.jar')
     compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.9'
     compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.9'
  }
```

Logcat

```
 Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class":
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.
However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.
If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.
If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
1 error; aborting
**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1**
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 59.141 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: have you tried `Invalidate cache and restart` in android studio?

Comment: Thank You for reply. Yes I tried Invalidate cache and restart option in android studio. But still facing the same error.

Comment: try cleaning your project and rebuilding

Comment: Then kindly post your full logcat

Comment: @gaurav cleaned the project and rebuild it. But still same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38451489/6648201

Comment: @gaurav When I used the solution mentioned as per "
 
stackoverflow.com/a/38451489/6648201 "
Got the these error:
Error:Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error:A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache POI will not work out of the box on Android due to various problems that you will run into when using bare Apache POI.

There are some projects that make it possible to use parts of Apache POI on Android:

1. https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx (for Android 5) and https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX (for Android 4), both are currently still based on Apache POI 3.12
2. https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/ (for Android 5, maintained by me), which can be more easily recompiled with newer versions of POI, e.g. it uses 3.15 currently

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before, try to add a deafultConfig

```
defaultConfig {

// Enabling multidex support.

multiDexEnabled true

}
```

Comment: Got the error " Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1"