# After updating Android studio library I cannot run or build project

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

I update my android studio 2.0 to latest 2.1.1 Also I update my sdk and install all required sdk elements.
After that when I run my existing working project then it give me bellow issue.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':lib-toolbarindicator:processReleaseResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/tristate/oldSdk/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

This error occur in messages tab. so I cannot go further in project.
Forgive me spieling mistake and grammatical mistake because I am not native in English.
Thank you

Comment: follow solutions provided on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle

Comment: aapt failure means you have errors in your resource files. You can get more information if you build from command line, `./gradlew clean assemble -i -s`

Comment: I clean project but it still not work

Answer (score 0):

Try to Clean up Your Project.
I often get Error but With Just One Clean shot, BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Answer (score 0):

Please change your build.gradel file then sync android because this type of error comes due to unnecessary complie library in build.gradel.

defaultConfig {
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}