# Android studio jdk finished with non-zero value 2

Tags: java, android, gradle

Ok, i know this topic is in stack overflow already, but i did everything i could, i did the multydex thing in my gradle, i did every answer i tried to get at stackoverflow, now i need really help on this, yesterday i was unable to run my app after 3 hs of trying to resolve this, hope you guys can bring me a hand

here is my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {



    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"




    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "myproject.myname.com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"



    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }





}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'





}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

here is my project gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

if i try to add the multidex = true and all the multiplex lines i got this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllReleaseClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzajj.class
```

im really confused and i cant find the answer since yesterday , if someone can help me i will be so glad, thanks

**UPDATE**

Ok , it seems the firebase compiles were causing the problem for the java jdk value error

after changing it to version 9.4.0 it worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle)

Comment: @shuvro  what i said in the post is that i know is a duplicate question, but i need certain attention to this problem because i cant solve it with all the other posts

Comment: do you have any  jar file in libs folder ?

Comment: @shuvro no, i dont have any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ffirebase:firebase-storage` ,'`com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0`','`com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:'  version to **9.4.0**  rather than 9.0.0

Let me know if this works for you .

Comment: Thanks shuvro, its really weird that it worked, i dont know why but its really really weird, hope it keeps working like this , i faced another error just before solving it, i might ask another question for now , but first im gonna do a little research, thanks and have a good day