# android studio java finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android, ubuntu

I installed the java jdk1.8.0_111 and installed android studio in ubuntu 16.04 (32 bits), but when I run android studio I get the message:

`Error:Process 'command '/usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`

[image: print screen]

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle

Comment: did you create a path variable to your jdk/jre ?

Comment: I added the java variable path in the etc/profile file @MerveSahin and, torpillo,  my build.gradle file doesn't java 2 java dependencies (I don't know how to show you the file here) and I think the problem is that Android Studio is executing two java's, my own, inside /usr/local/java/ and one from Android Studio, in /usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java, I went to Settings but couldn't find anywhere how to change that. If you find out how, please help me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the solution. I think Android Studio was using 2 java compilers, one built-in from android studio, and the other the one that I had installed in order to install Android Studio.

In **Android Studio**, On the menu **File -> Project Structure** : **change the default JDK location directory** to your own, in my case it was:

> /usr/local/android-studio/jre

and I **changed** to

> /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_111 #path_to_your_jdk

which is the version that I installed.

[image: Picture of the window]

Comment: @AbdellahRamadan you're welcome. I haven't test it on other Linux plataforms. Good that it worked on that too. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Works for me. A useful command to find out where the path of your jdk is on Linux is readlink -f $(which java). Then you can copy that path end at the jdk or java-x-oracle as the path to your jdk.