# Error:Process 'command '/usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, exit, ubuntu-14.10

Android Studio 2.2.3;
Java 8;
Ubuntu 14.10;
laptop: Asus K72F.

I spent no less than twenty hours on a Udacity course, learning the basics of XML as part of an Android course.

I installed Java on my Ubuntu machine, then Android Studio IDE.

Followed instructions on the course's videos and pages.
Tried saving my first project, but never made it to the first step...

**Error:Process 'command '/usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2**

I've found no intelligible instructions on the web.

I've been using Ubuntu, Linux, Mac OS X and Unix for ten years now, and I've solved one or two hundred problems with and without the command line, most often copying and pasting from Stack Overflow pages.

I've explored menus on Android Studio, I've opened lib folders. Some posts suggested changing libraries but failed to mention which ones and how.

Another post suggested changing "overrides" but, without a sealed project, Code > Override Methods stays grey and I can't act on it ... Another vicious circle.

One post suggested downgrading to Java 7. I thought the IDE setup for the Linux community might be slightly old, so I uninstalled Java 8 and got Java 7. Got rid of the IDE folder and reinstalled Android Studio, but this time I put it in /usr/local to play it safer. No, Java 7 wasn't supported so I had to upgrade and go back to Java 8.

I've been stuck for three weeks now. Yesterday I tried installing the latest version of this IDE on Windows but there's a bug and it crashes before opening.

I would appreciate it if you could state instructions taking nothing for granted, I am an absolute beginner with Android and gradle and the jargon is overwhelmingly different from Unix.

This reminds of the time when everybody suggested opening a Terminal window but nobody said how.

Please tell me which menus I have to go to, what lines to change, or which libraries to change and where to fetch them. 
Thank you for your time and trouble!

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android studio java finished with non-zero exit value 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682698/android-studio-java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, but when I entered good java path, I had a different problem, searched the solution for 3 days, and finally, this video gave me the answer...

Good luck!!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhj3MY4SpHY

EDITED:

So, the process looks like this.
1) after you download android studio and extract it to either /usr/local/ or /opt/, run it. When it gradles, you'll see an error "process 'command' /usr/loca/android-studio/jre/bin/java finished with non-zero exit value 2"

2) go to File->Project Structure->SDK Location an in there uncheck "Use embedded JDK". in the input field below that checkbox, paste or choose tha path of your JDK (mine was /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk).

3) Click OK, let gradle to do it's work, and when it's finished, you'll get 2 more errors (which I'm not gonna paste here) with lagre log (if you look at the log, on the beginning you should see something about unclosed quotes in aapt file in your /build-tools/25.0.0/aapt).

4) !!!!    I did this step to make sure that I have the same error like in the video, so it is optional   !!!!
I did a rebuild or clean. in the menu go to Build->Rebuild and start it. Your gradle should run forever so you can wait for a few minutes and if it's not finished, shut android studio down and proceed to the step 5.
If your gradle finishes, it's probablly not the error I'm tryng to expain.

5) When this is all done, opet the folder where your android apps are stored (for me the path is /home/matej/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/app), open your app (App name)->app->build.gradle

6) change the line "buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'" to
   "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'", save it and close

7) run the android studio again and you'll see the message where it links you to the installation of the missing build tools. click on it, install it and clean your project

8) ENJOY IN DEVELOPING :)

Comment: I apologize for not replying earlier. The YouTube video above did solve the problem, but then other errors came up. Basically, AndroidStudio does not work on my Ubuntu 14 laptop nor on my Windows 7 partition. I also tried the same IDE on a Win10 VM, but no luck with virtualization. In the end, I guess only MacOS (Yosemite, in my case) is fully and consistenly supported by Android Studio. I got my old Mac up and running and I'm working with it now. Not very happy about the situation, but also no choice.

Comment: strange, it should be working. After I found out about the video, I installed Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit and managed it to work without a flaw.
can you try that out?
also, before the video, I switched to win 10 and it worked there perfectlly.

Do you have 32bit or 64bit ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, 32-bit. At the moment, I don't have a machine that can sustain the weight of Ubuntu 16. Two years ago I also installed it on a Mac (a mid-2011 machine, and maybe it was Ubuntu 15) ... Not all drivers were available.

Comment: I had it installed on Ubuntu 14 32bit, but it worked fine, only problem I had with it on 32bit is that I couldn't get Simulators to work. otherwise it was excellent.
I'm sorry I can't help you out more. I'm just a beginner with both Ubuntu and Android studio, but since I need them for work, I feel obligated to post any findings about the problems I've solved on my own or with the help I got from outside this forum. 
If you find a solution, let me know, someone else might need it :)
good luck!

Comment: Thanks to Matej Maric. It's useful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had firebase database gradle versin lower than the latest one. Changing it to latest solved the issue.