# Android Studio 2.3.3 finished with non-zero exit value

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm really new to Andorid Studios 2.3.3 and have installed it on my Linux Mint.

When it starts I get this error message:

[image]

Do you guys got any ideas of how to get rid of it?

In the case above I have just started the studio with a new empty project.

Best regards
Fredrik

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android studio java finished with non-zero exit value 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682698/android-studio-java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2)

Comment: Make sure,  you are using the right JDK location.

Comment: are you in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Project Structure` from Android Studio.

1. Untick --> `Use Embedded JDK` if it is not properly directed to your project folder
2. Then manually find your own project path path, from there the problem will be solved.
3. Rebuild project and enjoy working. 
   P.S. I had also such problem, solved by this way

Comment: I put this in the path: