# problem with building to finish in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Could you help me with android studio.

I am new in android studio. I now installed  java version 8 and android studio->opened new Project, but I have an error, I have everytime in activity_main.xml  "Waiting for build to finish". I don't know why.

I am very thankfull if you can help me.

This is a Code:

```
package com.example.janyl.meinersteapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And this is a loyout

```
>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivityy"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main_activityy">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and it is a screen[https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wX23.png]

it is build.gradle file

```
    def var = apply(plugin: 'com.android.application')

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.janyl.meinersteapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-  layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to show Android Studio preview, the gradle should be synced or already having **a successful build** to show the Android Preview.

It says you should wait for the build to finish the task.

You can manage the tasks at the bottom of the Android Studio as follows if something is paused or not finished:

[image]

Or, try to rebuild the project from `Build -> Rebuild project` and if there were no issues/problems in the project, you should be able to see the preview after that.

Comment: :(it didn't help. It says 7 errors in activity_main.xml . But I didn't do anything

Comment: Because there are issues in your layout. That's why it cannot load the Preview. Would you paste the logcat or logs where those errors located in your question?

Comment: I opened a new project and there is the same problem. it said "Preview is unavailable a successful project sync" :(

Comment: That's exactly what I already explained in my answer. There are probably some issues in your project which you should paste the logcat or the logs which causes the issue. Can't help without checking logs or codes.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1

Comment: ok, thanks.  Is ndk important for android studio? I have linux mint 32 bit and I diidn't find ndk for 32 bit. I think it is the problem..But I am not sure. I have still the same problem

Comment: It is used to code [with c++](https://developer.android.com/ndk/) for Android. I don't use it honestly, I prefer the kotlin nowadays. Up to you BTW.

Comment: oh ok, then I don't know what the problem in my case is:((

Comment: What is the issue now? I don't see any issues with the ndk. Those were just layout issues which can be fixed easily, please clarify me with a screenshot of the errors so that I can help you.

Comment: [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GEQ4.png ] it says everytime  "Waiting for build to finish". I don't know why..

Comment: What version of Android Studio you are using? This happens because **there are multiple issues in your codes and you'll need to fix them first**. Then, if you run the app, the preview will show up **after a successful build** just like I said in my answer.

Comment: I use android version 3.2. I downloaded it 2 days ago. But I didn't write the code. I opened the new project and this code was here. I didn't do anything.  I did the same as here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bl8Q3Mi1x4I  . I am new in android and in programming..

Comment: Did you try suggested answers in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)? If you still see the exit with 0 zero error, show me your build.gradle file.

Comment: yes, I tried suggested answer in the link. but didn't help.  I added build.gradle in my question

Comment: I just saw. There seems to be no problem with that, can you please check this link too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40981824/4409113 This should probably help.

Comment: Yes I tried it yesterday. I changed to my jdk location which version I installed. but it didn't help