# Android Studio: Gradle execution failed while building the NDK application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

This part in the `build.gradle` file seems to be causing failures to execute the application.

The error message on the console:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command '/Users/marshall/android-sdks/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

the ndkBuild task is the one I defined in the `build.gradle` file. Here's the code block.

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask->compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

I double-checked if the directory of the ndk repository is correct, and it doesn't seem to be the reason for the failure.

Here's the entire `build.gradle` file's source code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.project"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
}
task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask->compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
}
```

Comment: https://www.crystax.net/blog/3

Comment: Can you please post your full `build.gradle`? You might have a look at this answer here. This might be the possible case. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30692005/3145960

Comment: @ReazMurshed I just uploaded the entire `build.gradle` source code. Can you check this out? Thx!!

Comment: You need to add `defaultConfig {multiDexEnabled true}` in your build.gradle

Comment: arrrrr this drives me crazy! I just tried that way and didn't work either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the Android SDK and NDK path to the `.bash_profile` file as follows.

`export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/opt/android-ndk`