# Cannot start my Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu

I am trying to start my first application on Android Studio in Ubuntu and every time it is showing this.
[image]

if anyone has any idea please help me.
I have already tried many of the changes like build.gradle, 65k issues for gradle but nothing is working for me.

This is the error:

> 10:21:27 PM Gradle sync failed: Process 'command '/var/www/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle)

Comment: If it just at the beginning it's not related with exceeding any limit, so try `/var/www/android-studio/jre/bin/java` from the command line and see what happens. BTW, strange dir to install studio.