# "C:\dev\sdk\android-sdk-essential\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe" finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, gradle

How can I solve this error:

```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. >
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> 'C:\dev\sdk\android-sdk-essential\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe''
> finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: Correct whatever problem is causing aapt.exe to finish with a non-zero exist value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do build apk first then afterwards it will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It solved!
I found a hint in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle). so I commented useless repositories such as:

```
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
```