# How do autocomplete with NativeScript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I need to do an `autocomplete` with `Nativescript`, but I did not find anything on the internet, what I need is that when typing, I send the typed text to an `API`, all I find is with an existing array.
Has anyone ever been through something and come up with a solution?

Comment: please share some code sample. What have you done till now? and where are you failing?

Comment: @Ashish I did not do anything the same, but I tried to use nativescript-ui-autocomplete that gave an error when running my application, so I took it.

Comment: please check out this link [github](https://github.com/Mohamed-saed/autocomplete-input-javascript) is using jquery but you can retype it easily to native javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Install

```
npm install nativescript-autocomplete
```

### Usage

IMPORTANT: Make sure you include `xmlns:ac="nativescript-autocomplete"` on the Page element

e.g

```
item:Array<string> = ['1','2','3','4']
itemTapped(args){
    const eventName = args.eventName;
    const data = args.data;
    const view = args.view;
    const index = args.index;
    const object = args.object;
}
<ac:Autocomplete  items="{{list}}" itemTap="itemTapped"/>
```

Source:https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-autocomplete
See this in case you have problem :https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-autocomplete/issues/8

Comment: whenever I try to use the error to generate the version


`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:runSbg'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org`

Comment: @RafaelAugusto it seems that the problem with the JDK version.

Comment: this appears on the terminal as well.


`nativescript-ui-autocomplete 4.2.0 for android is not compatible with the currently installed framework version 4.1.3.`

Comment: See this :https://github.com/shyiko/ktlint/issues/111 and this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle/32400904

Comment: Try to use :`var nativescriptUiAutocomplete = require("nativescript-ui-autocomplete" )` and specific the version  that compatible with your android.

Comment: See this:https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/741

Comment: without success in all links, funny is that if I take the plugin, it works again, when I put that breaks

Comment: The plugin above only supports Android.

Comment: I think the new version support because before it was in their TODO plan. See https://github.com/chrum/nativescript-autocomplete-x

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [RadAutoCompleteTextView](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/AutoCompleteTextView/autocomplete-getting-started)

Install

```
tns plugin add nativescript-ui-autocomplete
```

Supports Angular & Vue too.

Since you mentioned you will have an api that will return the values, you must need [Async Data](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/AutoCompleteTextView/autocomplete-aync-data).

More examples can be found in the [Github repo](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/tree/master/autocomplete/app/examples/remote-data-fetch).

Comment: I try this, but gave an error in my application when running

Comment: This plugin has a know issue with iOS devices. No indications that it will be fixed.
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/9031